# Log in Manually to different Connection than default on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have to switch users in controller function like this:

```
\DB::setDefaultConnection($connection);
Config::set('database.default', $connection);
$user->setConnection($connection);
Auth::login($user);
```

where `$user` is a user eloquent instance on another db connection, and `$connection` is the other(not default) connection. When I try to log in, it logs the user on the default connection using the `id` of the user that is on another connection.

How can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: Check this out https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-5-multiple-database-connection

Comment: @KelvinKyaw Retrieving the user is not the issue. Manual Log in with `Auth::login($user)` is the challenge

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new connection in `config/database.php`

```
'another_connection' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_OTHER_HOST', ''),
        'port'     => env('DB_OTHER_PORT', ''),
        'database' => env('DB_OTHER_DATABASE', ''),
        'username' => env('DB_OTHER_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_OTHER_PASSWORD', ''),
    ],
```

In your Eloquent model, tell it to use the new connection. Afterwhich, you can use it as normally you would.

```
protected $connection = 'another_connection';
```

Comment: I can not hard code the connection as this will change at run time. So my queries are like:
`$user = User::on($connection)->where('email', 'mail@test.com')->first();`